# How to write any UDF getting value according any index gap?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i want to write a UDF which uses String Value and starting index number and count number like that:

GetValueUDF("i am 18 years old.",6,2)  output: 18 ,   6: .nth starting point, 2: count

GetValueUDF("i am 101 years old.",6,3)  output: 101

GetValueUDF("i am 101 years old.",1,4)  output: "i am"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quite sure why you want to create a user defined function for this since that is what the `substring` function does.  But you should be able to use something like the following:

```
create function GetValueUDF
(
  @string varchar(max), 
  @startPosition int,
  @length int
)
returns varchar(max)
as

begin
  return substring(@string, @startPosition, @length)
end
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1aa65/2)